# How do I find a file with a name which depends on the current date (and a random component)?

Tags: shell, find, date

I have to check a particular path every day and find the file with a name of the form:

```
StaticData_Sets_yyyymmdd-232550.txt
```

The date in the name after the string `StaticData_Sets_` is updated every day depending on the system date. The number after the date is random.

How can I find the file for the current date in Unix?

Answer (score 5):

Use command `date` to generate current day with proper output format, and append that string to file name in the following fashion:

```
filename=StaticData_Sets_$(date +"%Y%m%d")
find . -name "$filename*.txt"
```

Comment: May be interesting to use `"${filename}*.txt"` to make clear where the name of the variable ends.

Answer (score 1):

That `find` command should find the file with todays date:

```
find /path/ -regex ".*\/StaticData_Sets_$(date +%Y%m%d)-[0-9]+\.txt"
```

It find all that contain `/StaticData_Sets_`, then the date in your desired format, and then a digit (`[0-9]+`).

Comment: Jaipreet if you're trying to find yesterday's file instead of today's file, then replace `$(date +%Y%m%d)` with `$(date --date=yesterday +%y%m%d)`. See `man date` and read the short section under "DATE STRING" or for a very long treatise on the subject, try `info date` and read section "28 Date input formats". It's very flexible in that you can even say something esoteric like `date --date="next tuesday 2 years ago"`

Answer (score 1):

If the file is directly under the path you are given (no extra subdirectories) then this should work.

```
file=$path/StaticData_Sets_$(date +"%Y%m%d")-*.txt
```

If there are then this should work (might need to manually enable `globstar` in bash).

```
    file=$path/**/StaticData_Sets_$(date +"%Y%m%d")-*.txt
```