# Find a file with a naming pattern

Tags: find

I have a file in a particular location. The file name is in format
`StaticData_Sets_yyyymmdd-hh:mm:ss.txt`

This file is generated everyday with current date and timestamp.The string `StaticData_Sets_` remains same for all files and only the date and time varies.

I just want to find the file with current day stamp(irrespective of time). And check the size of the file is 0 or not.

Comment: Déjà vu: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164558/how-do-i-find-a-file-with-a-name-which-depends-on-the-current-date-and-a-random

Comment: Why would you repost exactly the same question when you already have answers in your other one?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current date in that format with:

```
date +%Y%m%d
```

so the following command should find today's file and show its size:

```
ls -l StaticData_Sets_$(date +%Y%m%d)*.txt
```

or

```
find . -name "Static_Data_Sets_$(date +%Y%m%d)*.txt" -ls
```

You could sort the output using `ls -lt` and look at the topmost entry, which should be either today, or yesterday. In that case you would have to remember yourself what date it is.

Comment: Thanks. I just want to know what is wrong wit this command find . -name 'StaticData_Sets_$(date +"%Y%m%d")*'. When i try this it doenst work out.

Comment: That just finds the file it doesn't show the size, for that you would need to add `-ls` at the end. If that is not it, what is not working out?

Comment: Could you please help me perform the same task using find command.

Comment: @Jaipreet I updated the answer